# grid-template-columns moves middle line to sides when screen is small

Tags: html, css

My key objective is to make a timeline-like section, where my projects will be on two sides of a middle line (which is a timeline line). I can handle it when the screen is big but when the screen size is small, on mobile, the middle line just disappeared. 
This is what I plan to create on fullscreen:

```
 Hello World   |             
               |      3      

       2       |             
               | 4
```

This is what I plan to create on small screen:

```
    |    Hello World
    |      3      

    |      2    
    |     4
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@200;300;400&display=swap');
.timeline {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.timeline-content {
  overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.timeline-component {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 689px) {
  .timeline {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3px 1fr;
  }
  .timeline-middle {
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #F27121, #E94057, #8A2387);
    width: 3px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .main-middle {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .timeline-circle {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #F27121, #E94057, #8A2387);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline-empty">
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-middle">
    <div class="timeline-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-component timeline-content">
    <p>Time line 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-component timeline-content">
    <p>Time line 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-middle">
    <div class="timeline-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-empty">
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-empty">
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-middle">
    <div class="timeline-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class=" timeline-component timeline-content">
    <p>Time line 3</p>
  </div>
```

But in reality, 
This is when screen size is fullscreen
[image]

This is when screen is small
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, divide `.timeline` into separate blocks, and be consistent when outputting html.

Second, if you want to apply styles to lines and circles in general, don't write them in a media query `@media (min-width: 689px)`.

I made one of the options for solving the task for you (the `order` property did the trick):

```css
.timeline {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.timeline-content {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 10%;
}

.timeline-middle{
  order: -1;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #F27121, #E94057, #8A2387);
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
}

.timeline-circle {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #F27121, #E94057, #8A2387);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.timeline-empty{
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 689px) {
  .timeline {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3px 1fr;
  }
  .timeline:nth-child(even) .timeline-middle{
    order: 1;
  }
  .timeline:nth-child(even) .timeline-content{
    order: 2;
  }
  .timeline-empty{
    display: block;
  }
  .timeline-middle {
    order: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline-component timeline-content">
    <p>Time line 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-middle">
    <div class="timeline-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-empty"></div>
</div>
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline-component timeline-content">
    <p>Time line 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-middle">
    <div class="timeline-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-empty"></div>
</div>
<div class="timeline"> 
  <div class=" timeline-component timeline-content">
    <p>Time line 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-middle">
    <div class="timeline-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-empty"></div>
</div>
```